# Number Range w/ a designated output

Tags: python

So I'm having an issue where I'm trying to write a program that has a numerical input and also ask for a class category output. The problem I'm running into currently is I don't think I'm using the proper setup for my desired output. This is what I'm currently at:

```
     miles = int(input("How many miles have you traveled?"))

    if miles >= 10000:
            print("You are a part of Class Z")
    elif miles >= 50000:
            print("You are a part of Class C")
    elif miles >= 100000:
            print("You are a part of Class B")
    elif miles <= 100000:
            print("You are a part of Class A")

main()
```

Should I be doing a range instead of what I'm currently doing? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should test the largest value first, because eg. for a Class A with over 100,000, it would still be over 10000 miles and therefore sorted into Class Z.

Try changing up the order of your `if` statements to solve this problem.

Comment: Appreciate it. I switched it around and plugged that back into my program and it's pulling the proper output I need.